# Teaser Class Node ID

Tags: views, 7, theming, display-suite, nodes

I have created a views page which displays teasers.

Is there a way I can apply teaser node id as a class of the teaser's row. Currently I am getting these classes

> views-row views-row-8 views-row-even **and** views-row views-row-9 views-row-odd views-row-last

[image]

Comment: Sure, just create a template file for row display of that view, and preprocess it. Views even tells you what the template file needs to be called under Advanced -> Theme

Comment: @clive Thanks, I have found this code in theme information you have referred. can you tell me how to get the node id in this <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>

Comment: Difficult to say...try printing `get_defined_vars()` in the template file, it should show you what you have to work with